# How to unit test a void method with no arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, switch-statement, mockito

I need to test a class to determine if a relevant action has taken place given a certain input. The code goes something like this:

```
protected static void receiveInput() {
    String command;
    boolean b = true;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (b) {

        command = scanner.next();
        switch(command) {

            case "first":
                System.out.println("First!");
                break;

            case "second":
                System.out.println("Second!");
                break;

            case "third":
                System.out.println("Third!");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("\n***** Invalid *****\n"); 
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

I can probably get a pretty thorough unit test if I can somehow control the command string and keep track of the scanner object. For some reason, I'm actually not allowed to inject those two objects as arguments for this method. What options are there for doing this test a different way?

Comment: You can't make this a value-returning function of type `string` and just return the specific case string to check against?

Comment: Are you able to change this method to make it more unit-test friendly?

Comment: This isn't a very unit-test friendly method.  Usually for me, when I'm unit testing void methods it's because they produce some sort of side effect or state change.  I then test if that side effect occurred correctly.  Unfortunately, in this case it's going to be quite hard to unit-test without changing the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to MattPutnam's excellent answer, there are two specific tips for your method.

1.Change to returning strings

```
protected static string receiveInput(String arg) {
    String result;
    String command = arg;
    boolean b = true;

    while (b) {
        switch(command) {

            case "first":
                result = "first";
                break;

            case "second":
                result = "second";
                break;

            case "third":
                result = "third";
                break;

            default:
                result = "\n ****Invalid*** \n"; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

2.My preference would just to test if `boolean b` is true or not. If it's true, you know it worked, if not, it didn't. **Edit:** Note that this could be dangerous as you won't be checking that `arg` necessarily fit the string criteria but rather that it had an acceptable answer.

About the only way you're going to test this current method is to somehow catch the stream as **MattPutnam** answered in the comments.

Comment: dangerous just to prove the Boolean... and I would suggest to extract the whole logic to an own method as MattPutman said...

Comment: Which is why I had listed it after number 1. I see why you say it could be dangerous now that I read my answer. I'll edit.

Comment: @MilesPeterson, I would strongly suggest you accept MattPutnam's answer

Answer (score 22):

This is a perfect example for making functions more testable.  This function takes no input and produces no output, affecting the world only via side effect, making it completely untestable through standard means.

To refactor this function to make it more testable:

- Don't ask the user for input via scanner, take the user's input as an input parameter.
- Don't print the result, return it.

The caller of the function can then decide how to provide the inputs and what to do with the output.  Your modified program can ask for user input, call the function, then print the output.  A testing framework can supply the input from a list of inputs to test, and check the outputs against the expected values.

Comment: You can wrap the "business logic" in a testable method that takes the input and returns the output, keeping your `void` method intact.  Probably more desirable would be to have the method accept two parameters, InputStream (or Reader) and OutputStream (or Writer, or PrintWriter)

Comment: You mentioned standard means. Does that mean there are other ways to unit test? That's really what I'm looking for.

Comment: To test as-is, you'd have to intercept the input and output streams.  It can be done, but it's ugly as hell.

Comment: Great answer! there is a great book, I suggest to everyone, no matter how experienced... Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship by Robert C. Martin...

Comment: Let's assume I'm going to try testing I/O. How would I write that in a way that would capture the function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream) to modify System.in and read from a file or a ByteArrayInputStream.

In the same way, use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream) to redirect the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the output with the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) library.

```
public class YourTest {
  @Rule
  public SystemOutRule log = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();
  @Rule
  public TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();

  @Test
  public void test() {
    systemInMock.provideLines("first", "second");
    ... //execute your code
    assertEquals("First!\nSecond!\n", log.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator());
  }
}
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of System Rules.